# How to disable response caching in Falcon Framework?

Tags: python, falconframework

I'm developing an API so I need to make several tests on routes, but Falcon is caching my responses, even if I change data on the db I wont show on a response until a restart the server (in this case waitress).

I'm on Windows right now, so I cant use gunicorn.

Comment: I've heard Waitress is a good alternative for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use (at least for development) Werkzeug is easy to setup, has autoreload on changes and i think (from my experience) it will remove your cache issues

Here it is my setup:

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from config import api

#api is the falcon app
run_simple("127.0.0.1", 8000, api, use_reloader=True, passthrough_errors=False)
```